# Mcrypt PHP extension required on MacOS Yosemite Apache

Tags: php, macos, terminal, mcrypt, osx-yosemite

When running a php command in terminal I keep getting "Mcrypt PHP extension required." I have installed Mcrypt using the instructions [here](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/install-mcrypt-php-mac-osx-10-10-yosemite-development-server/) and phpinfo does show that it is enabled (Version: 2.5.8, Api No: 20021217).  How can I get this to work to stop PHP from erroring?

Comment: It turns out the issue was that I had inadvertently installed multiple versions of PHP on the laptop! I gave up on the mess, and brought it to a dev ops member who helped me sort out my versions.

For anyone else with this issue, check for multiple versions using different configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the linked instructions, you've probably enabled the extension only for the SAPI used by Apache.

There's usually a separate config file (*/etc/php-cli.ini* or something like that), which also has to be modified for CLI to load the extension.

Comment: I dont seem to have a /etc/php-cli.ini at all, could that be part of the problem?

Comment: I don't think so ... If you need a config file for something, it's always present.

Comment: Sorry I let it go so long.  It turns out the issue was that I had inadvertently installed multiple versions of PHP on the laptop!  I gave up on the mess, and brought it to a dev ops member who helped me sort out my versions.

For anyone else with this issue, check for multiple versions using different configurations.